# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Unstable network connection

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a problem in my computer clients that are connected in my windows server 2012 R2. I have 30 client computers and sometimes other computers are not connected in my domain. For example 28 computers are connected in my SERVER.COM(my domain) while the others are connected to Network.